# Use JSON Schema to get all values of a certain type (HTML string)

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema

I trying to select only the HTML strings from a JSON file which contains objects, strings and HTML strings. This is how the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "person1": {
    "name": "Marcus",
    "bio": "<h2>Academic</h2><p>Lorem ipsum <em>dolores</em> sit amet. Conquistat ergo sum.</p>"
  },
  "person2": {
    "name": "Philipp",
    "bio": "<h2>Academic</h2><p>Ipsum lorem <em>vencit</em> sit amet. Conquistat ergo sum.</p>"
  }
}
```

To separate the normal strings from the HTML strings I have introduced the key `"format" : "html"`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": { 
          "type": "string"
          },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "bio": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "html"
        }
      },
      "required": ["name", "age", "bio"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Question: How do I select all values which have the `"format" : "html"` attribute?**

Using a custom key/value maybe isn't the most elegant solution and I'm thinking about switching to a more [standard solution](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html#rfc.section.4.3.2). The reason I want to get the HTML strings is that they need to be validated and [sanitized](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sanitize-html).

The applications itself is build on node.js, so recommendations for node-modules which help my with this JSON/JSON schema thing are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used a JSON pointer to `/person/bio`:

```
function getValue(object, path) {
    object = object || {};

    if (path === "") {
        return object;
    }

    var fragments = path.split("/"),
    iter = 0, key,
    length = fragments.length,
    result = object;

    while (result != null && iter < length) {
        key = fragments[iter];
        if (key !== "#") {
             result = result[key];
        }
        iter += 1;
    }

    return result || null;
}
```